# How to get revision number of latest commit in master branch

Tags: git

I am trying to find a command which can help me find the "revision" number of `origin/master`. the command should be able to find the revision from any branch which is currently checked out.

Assuming that i am in `git rev-list --max-count=1 HEAD --remotes=master`. But it didn't give me "Correct" revision number. It gave me a revision number which was 3-4 commits behind. So not sure if it fetched that from `master` or from local.

Comment: Worth pointing out: revisions aren't exactly *numbered*. They are *named* by their unique hash ID. Each commit stores some number of *parent* hash IDs, and `git rev-list` walks the graph obtained by starting at any particular set of commits and working through their parents.

Comment: Note, too, that except for commands that reach out to another Git (`git ls-remote`, `git fetch`, and `git push`, with `git pull` meaning *run `git fetch`, then run a second command locally*), *no* Git operation gets anything remotely. The `git fetch` operation is the one that brings commits *from* another Git into your own repository, so that you can see and work with them.

Answer (score 4):

You mean, revision id?

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Comment: Was the question changed? Because if my memory is not playing games with me, you were asking about the revision of what you had checked out, is that right?

Comment: Oh, I see... actually, my memory is not playing games... I was guided by this: `[t]he command should be able to find the revision from any branch which is currently checked out.`. So, there you go. What is currently checked out is **HEAD**, any time of the day.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Not sure about a git command, but `cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master` will get you commit hash of origin/master.</s>

Per Ulysse BN's comment, the corresponding git command would be `git rev-parse origin/master`

You can show additional information with `git show origin/master` or `git log -1 origin/master`

Comment: Or you could use `git rev-parse origin/master` as well

Comment: it is better to use the `rev-parse` command since refs could be packed and not available as a simple file.